# Unix OVO (hp operations manager) suppressing an alert with backslash

Tags: unix, character, protected, backslash

I'm trying to suppress an alert in a system called HP Operations manager probably more commonly known as OVO (very old system i know) however i'm struggling with the UNIX protected characters because i am trying to suppress a windows alert from    the Microsoft\Windows path, so anything before it and after it in the log file can change just want to exclude everything from Microsoft\Windows.

I have tried using double backslashes \ as i have done some research and found that the first \ mitigates the meaning of the second \ therefore \ = \, this doesn't work for me, so far I've got <*>"\Microsoft\Windows"<*> that doesn't work, but i have also tried  \Microsoft\Windows to no avail.

I don't really have a test platform so it's been just trial and error so far, however i will know when it finally works because i will no longer receive these alerts.

Long story short is i want to know how to handle windows file paths e.g xxx\xxx\xxx\ in UNIX so what do i change \Microsoft\Windows to for it to be recognized in UNIX

Comment: Ive been using http://www.softpanorama.org/Admin/HP_operations_manager/Policies/Conditions/patterns.shtml to help me understand but don't get it might make more sense to somebody on here, thank you

Comment: Not really a programming code Q of the `if/else/endif` variety. May be more appropriate on https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com . Some systems provide a function to convert between forms, some systems know how to do it automatically (apparently not OVO, or could it be an ENV var?). If your still under contract for support on this, file a ticket, else search the documentation.

Comment: Oh, and try the user forums on https://ittoolbox.com (I can't reach there right now). I used to get the best answers on AIX stuff there, but you'll have to figure out which forum is best for HP. Also worth looking at the HP support forums. Good luck.

Comment: ah, it's https://it.toolbox.com/questions might get you started . This site seems reorganized since I last was active, I recall registering and having access to a list of groups you could join. Pretty sure there was an HP admin group. See what your google-fu can find.  Good luck.

Comment: And, an obscure system I use has a utility `unixpath` that takes `c:\my\path` and turns it into `/c/my/path` . See if your system has a similar utility OR the reverse? `winpath` (or `dospath`). The link you provided seems way over the top for the problem you are describing. That's all I got ;-) . Good luck!